# How to get parent of selected child row in a JXTreeTable

Tags: java, swing, parent, swingx, jxtreetable

I'm a beginner to Java programming and have been designing a tree table using JXTreeTable. My tree table has 2 levels - parent nodes and child nodes. I want a display a graph next to the tree table based upon which child row the user has selected. The graph is fetched based on the parent/child node path.

My question is, what is the best way to retrieve the parent node of a selected child row?

Comment: Assuming you have the child node, you should be able to use `getParent` to get the parent node, but this all subjective without know how you're building your table...*"I'm a beginner to Java programming"* ... and you've just taken on two of the most complex components of the Swing API (outside of the text components)...lots of fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** what is the best way to retrieve the parent node of a selected child row
**A:** selectedChild.getParent();

https://pirlwww.lpl.arizona.edu/resources/guide/software/SwingX/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html